# Can FFMPEG extract still images from video based on video "SMPTE timecode" hh:mm:ss:ff?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, screenshot, extract

Is there any way to extract still images from video  based on video "own SMPTE" timecode? (hour:minute:second:frame) as seen in the "Timecode Handler" recognized by ffmpeg.

I would like to create screenshots. (exactly the same frames) from different sources. Soureces length is not the same,(sometimes small segments), but the smpte timecode always is.

I'm looking for something like this, with the difference that instead of hh:mm:ss it uses the Timecode Handler TimeCode?

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:04 -i input.mp4 -frames:v 1 %04d.png
```

Thanks.

Comment: Read the timecode on one line of the script and store it in a variable, then use that variable in way you want. This is dependent on the scripting tool you use, not on features that are probably not built in to ffmpeg.